Is it acceptable if I put an Umweltplakette to the top-right instead of the bottom-right corner of the windshield?
I obtained an "Umweltplakette" sticker abroad, and the instructions asked to place the sticker to the top-right or bottom-right corner of the car's windshield (viewed from the driver's perspective). I placed it to the top corner, since it obscures less the driver's view.
However then I learned that the German instructions explicitly ask to place it to the bottom corner:

Is this a problem? Can I be fined because of that?

The 35. BImSchV, the legal norm that governs the Umweltplakette, is pretty clear on where to place the badge:

Zur Kennzeichnung eines Kraftfahrzeuges ist die Plakette deutlich sichtbar auf der Innenseite der Windschutzscheibe anzubringen.

Translated:

The environmental badge must be placed clearly visible on the inside of the windscreen.

So, as long as the badge is placed on the inside of the windscreen, and clearly visible, the exact placement does not matter. You don't risk being fined by placing it in the upper corner.

but make sure it's NOT behind any heavily tinted strip that may make it hard(er) to see from the outside! Which might make placement on top illegal depending on applicable law.
